# How to understand "Faust" without foreknowledge?

Tags: literature

Hello fellow German speakers,
perhaps the most of you had to read Goethes Faust in school. My question now is, did anybody back in the days understand the play without preparations? I have to admit that the German language changed over the decades but IMHO not even the royals could have been able to follow with ease?

Danke für eure Antworten!

Comment: Is German a foreign language to you?

Comment: Nope. I'm a native speaker. Still would be overwhelmed if I had to watch it without careful preparations of my teacher.

Comment: Warum schreibst du dann die Frage auf Englisch?

Comment: Weil es mehr um das Stück im allgemeinen geht. Aber du hast recht, jemand mit nicht ausreichend guten Deutschkenntnissen könnte mir die Frage eh nicht beantworten. (Stackoverflow/Stackexchange wird für mich immer eine englischsprachige Seite bleiben )

Comment: _Foreknowledge_ of what exactly? Historic context? Role playing in general? Dramaturgy?

Comment: The play in general and especially the choice of words. It's kinda hard to follow if you can't understand the meaning even though you can understand the words.

Comment: @Peter If that satisfies you, the answer is _No, you can't_.

Comment: What Royals? Don’t get the reference...

Comment: Like the upper class during Gothes era. The only people who could even read.

Comment: I have to disagree with @πάνταῥεῖ - it’s possible. For the record: my 12yo (who admittedly isn’t your average child) just pulled our Reclam edition off the bookshelf because he wanted to find out what exactly the big hoopla was, read it and declared it “overrated”.

Comment: Vielleicht weil es schon spät ist, aber was genau meinst du mit "hoopla"? Hut ab, wenn er einfach so Faust gelesen hat und dazu noch den historischen Kontext verstanden hat.

Comment: @Perer Hopplah - Weil man den Begriff “der Faust” halt immer mal wieder hört - es also wohl ein „bedeutendes“ Werk ist, um das eben ein gewisses Brimborium gemacht wird. Keine Ahnung, wie und wo mein Ableger da überhaupt drauf kam, evtl. über die Schule? Ist Abithema dieses Jahr...

Comment: Solange es bei Faust I bleibt, ist ja noch alles gut. 

Comment: @Peter: Der Faust wurde 1808 veröffentlicht, nicht im finstren Mittelalter. Lt. Wikipedia (Schulpflicht) wurde 1717 in Preußen die allgemeine Schulpflicht eingeführt, allerdings nicht durchgesetzt. Immerhin besagt eine Statistik von 1818, dass 60% der Kinder in Schulen registriert waren. Also sicher nicht exklusiv die Oberklasse.

Comment: Ist die Frage "*How to understand ...*" (wie im Titel) oder "*...did anybody ... understand...?*" wie im Text?

Answer (score 5):

Gute Kunstwerke können auf vielen Ebenen genossen werden.

Man kann in eine Faust-Vorstellung gehen und sich einfach über das amüsante Spektakel freuen mit den schrillen Hexen und dem lustigen Pudel und so weiter. Man kann sich auch, mit entsprechender Vorbildung, an der Wortkunst mit den pfiffigen Reimen freuen oder auch an der Stimmgewalt der Schauspieler (ohne überhaupt weiter auf den Sinn zu achten). Mit noch mehr Vorbildung und Belesenheit kann man auch den mehr oder weniger tiefsinnigen philosophischen Erwägungen folgen,  die Goethe da hineingezwirbelt hat, und man kann sich freuen, wenn man Zitate und Anspielungen auf andere Werke der (v.a.) deutschen Literatur erkennt.

Es geht in keinem Fall darum, den "Sinn" zu verstehen. Der "Sinn" eines Textes ist kein Fixum, das der Autor ein für allemal dem Text eingebaut hat. Vielmehr ergibt sich beim Konsumenten des Sprachkunstwerks bei jedem Konsumakt (sprich: Lesen, Theaterbesuch) ein Sinn aufs Neue, und dieser hängt vollkommen ab von der gegenwärtigen Situation des Konsumenten: Lebenslage, Stimmung, Vorbildung: Ist er gerade hungrig? Ist ihm die Freundin weggelaufen? Hat er ein eigenes Gretchen im Auge, das er gerne bürsteln möchte, doch sie lässt ihn nicht? Ist er Theologe, Mediziner oder Physiker? Oder ist er ein Mädchen vom Lande, das sich wundert, ob es mit dem spinnerten Typ von der Uni ausgehen soll, und was will der eigentlich von ihr, und was macht der Hund dabei? Hat er als Automobilindustriemanager gerade eine illegale Abgassteuerung durchgewunken und damit seine Seele verkauft? In jeder dieser Situationen wird er in einem vielschichtigen Kunstwerk wie dem "Faust" Dinge finden, die ihn gerade ansprechen, und er wird vielleicht meinen, dass der Autor beim Schreiben genau an ihn gedacht hat. Das hat dieser zwar nicht, aber in der breiten Anwend- und Auslegbarkeit des Textes liegt seine Stärke und der Grund, warum er auch nach Jahrhunderten noch taugt.

Die Frage, ob Bauern und Adlige, Handwerker und Beamte, Bettler und Gelehrte den "Faust" seinerzeit "verstanden" haben, stellt sich darum für mich nicht. Wer immer in eine Vorführung gegangen ist (zeittypisch vermutlich  mitsamt Picknickkorb), hat seinen eigenen Sinn daraus gezogen.

Man kann allerdings annehmen, dass im allgemeinen ein gewisses Grundverständnis der Kern-Story relativ verbreitet war, weil Goethes "Faust" ja auch nur die überkomplizierte x-te Variation einer damals als Volkserzählung recht populären Gruselgeschichte war.